# network on main thread exception still not resolved by a separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Your implementation
                                clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.112", 9874);
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    //ClientReceiveThread clientReceiveThread = new ClientReceiveThread(clientSocket,textview);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

even of I am trying to perform a network task on a separate thread why it still gives me network on main thread exception

Comment: Please add the stack trace to the question.

Comment: Don't mix text and binary streams unless you like confusion. Try to stick to one or the other.

Comment: If the IP address doesn't resolve, it doesn't matter whether you use a background thread or not.